# Exacttarget data extension - How to retrieve all rows in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a landing page that needs to display a list of all the records in a data extension in real time. In the past we have done this with a subset of the data using the LookupRows function. This works great, but from what I can see it only returns a subset not the entire data extension.

Is there a way in ampscript to return all the rows from a Data Extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this is to create a field in the data extension that has a default value, since this value will be the same for every record you use this field/value pair as your lookup criteria.

So for example add a field called "return", with a default value of "1". Then use this code:

```
LookupRows("YOUR DE NAME","return","1")
```

This isn't recommended for large data sets.

Comment: I had discovered this before posting this, but I wondered if there was a better way. It appears there isn't. Thanks for the reply.